# Parse a JSON object value (an Array), not the object

Tags: android, facebook, spring, gson

I'm developing an Android application that connects with Facebook using Springframework Android rest client.

With this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AUTH_TOKEN
```

Facebook API returns:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Friend1",
         "id": "123456"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to parse the `data[]` values, as an array:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Friend1",
        "id": "123456"
    }
]
```

And get a `FacebookFriend[]`.

**How can I do it with `GSON`?**

Comment: Again downvoting and don't say it why. Very instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'd need a `FacebookFriend` class (using public fields and no getters for simplicity):

```
public class FacebookFriend {
    public String name;
    public String id;
}
```

If you created a wrapper class such as:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    public List<FacebookFriend> data;
}
```

Life becomes far simpler as you can simply do:

```
JsonResponse resp = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonString, JsonResponse.class);
```

And be done with it.

If you don't want to create an enclosing class with a `data` field, you'd use Gson to parse the JSON, then extract the array:

```
JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
JsonElement e = p.parse(myJsonString);
JsonObject obj = e.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray ja = obj.get("data").getAsJsonArray();
```

(You can obviously chain all those methods, but I left them explicit for this demonstration)

Now you can use Gson to map directly to your class.

```
FacebookFriend[] friendArray = new Gson().fromJson(ja, FacebookFriend[].class);
```

That said, honestly it's better to use a `Collection` instead:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<FacebookFriend>>(){}.getType();
Collection<FacebookFriend> friendCollection = new Gson().fromJson(ja, type);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, your array contain object.

you can parse it in following way.

```
    JsonArray array = jsonObj.get("data").getAsJsonArray();
    String[] friendList = new String[array.size()];
   // or if you want JsonArray then
   JsonArray friendArray = new JsonArray();
    for(int i=0 ; i<array.size(); i++){
         JsonObject obj = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
         String name = obj.get("name").getAsString();
          friendList[i] = name;
          // or if you want JSONArray use it. 
          friendArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(name));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed my question with more details.

Comment: i can't get your point. If i'm not wrong, you want to add data[] values into another array?

Comment: I want to get data[] values an parse them as an array. I've updated my question again.

Comment: I update my answer for both scenario if you want Java array or JsonArray.